# how to get JSON value through Dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, cordova, drop-down-menu

We have JSON like this

```
"[{\"UserID\":1,\"Name\":\"demo\"},{\"UserID\":4,\"Name\":\"ekova\"},{\"UserID\":2,\"Name\":\"Himansu-it\"},{\"UserID\":3,\"Name\":\"Himansu-it Services\"}]"
```

We need Show UserName to drop-down list and if I Select Name on dropdown  We need to get UserID.Like if We Select ekvoa We need get UserID 4

We show userName drop Down like this

```
function selectitems(){

     var getCustomerIDs = jQuery.parseJSON( customerID );

        $(getCustomerIDs).each(function() {
    console.log(this.UserID);
    console.log(this.Name);
    $('#date').append('<option>'+this.Name+'</option>');

        });
}
```

We need to post UserID like this

```
$.ajax({

            url:'http://www.himansuit.com/DemoSalesApp/MyService.svc/GetCurrentGeoLocationsByUserID/'+userID,
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            type:'get',
            cache:false,
            timeout: 10000,
            error: function(x, t, m) {
        if(t==="timeout") {
            debugger;
            $('#alertmessage').empty();

             alert("NO Internet Connection");
          // withOutNetConnection();
        } else {
            //alert(t);
        }},
            success:function(data) {
                debugger;
                GetAllElementsjson=data;

       elements();

    }
    });
```

Please guide me .

Comment: have write select box change event code?

Comment: Where is ur dropdown

Comment: @Sandeeproop button action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the value of the option to the UserID like so:

```
$('#date').append('<option value="'+this.UserID+'">'+this.Name+'</option>');
```

Then when #date changes, you can grab the value (`$('#date').val()`), which should be the userid.

Answer (score 0):

Add user id as a value in option.get selected option on change event of select box(#date')

```
$('#date').append('<option value='+this.UserID+'>'+this.Name+'</option>');
```

call ajax on change event of (#date).

```
 $('#date').on('change',function(){
   var  userID = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        url:'http://www.himansuit.com/DemoSalesApp/MyService.svc/GetCurrentGeoLocationsByUserID/'+userID,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        type:'get',
        cache:false,
        timeout: 10000,
        error: function(x, t, m) {
    if(t==="timeout") {
        debugger;
        $('#alertmessage').empty();

         alert("NO Internet Connection");
      // withOutNetConnection();
    } else {
        //alert(t);
    }},
        success:function(data) {
            debugger;
            GetAllElementsjson=data;

   elements();

  }
  });
 })
```